# how to fetch JSON dictionary/array with Alamofire 4.0 and show it on tableView Cell

Tags: swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to fetch a HomeFeed for an app, as this is my 1st major app.
 I am finding it difficult fetch the JSON data and show it on my `tableViewCell` , particularly converting the `JSON Array/Dictionary` and to use it.
 Any kind of help would be much appreciated and life saver !!

Here is my `HomeFeedTableView` class :

```
class HomeFeedTableView: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var cameraBtn: UIButton!
var tableView = UITableView()


var tableAuthor = [String]()
var tableTitle = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //cameraBtn possition
    cameraBtn.layer.zPosition = 1000

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    getJSON()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// Get JSON
func getJSON(){

    let getEndPoint: String = "http://myURL/api/get_user_post/"
    Alamofire.request(getEndPoint)
        .responseJSON { response in

            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            if let value =  response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value)
                //print(json.description)

                for items in json.dictionary! {

                    //let author: String? = anItem["author"].stringValue
                    //let title: String? = anItem["title"].stringValue
                    //self.tableAuthor.append(author!)
                    //self.tableTitle.append(title!)

                    print(items)

                }



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    }

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return status.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...

    let cell: HomeFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell") as! HomeFeedTableViewCell
    let img = UIImage(named: imageMain[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    cell.ImageMain.image = img
   // cell.statusMain.text = tableAuthor[indexPath.row]

    let proImg = UIImage(named: imageMain[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    cell.profileImage.image = proImg
    cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20.00
    cell.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.likeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.2
    cell.likeBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.likeBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.likeBtn.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.commentBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.2
    cell.commentBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.commentBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.commentBtn.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}

@IBAction func cameraBtnClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Camera Clicked")
}

}
```

And I got this JSON response

```
("main_content", [
 {
   "author" : "maruf khandakar",
   "post_id" : 110,
   "post_date" : "October 3, 2016",
   "title" : "hjhjhjhjkljkhasfreiwutb cltjutjuregjre nb",
   "show_comment_number" : "0",
   "show_likes" : "0",
   "post_img" : [
  {
   "guid" : "http:\/\/myURL\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1475492476.jpg"
      }
],
 "author_img" : "http:\/\/myUrl\/wp-  content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/Screenshot_1-2.png",
   "post_time" : "11:01 am",
   "blog_text" : "sfdhjusolidasfjgfkdsjfdklshfj"
  },
 {
"author" : "maruf khandakar",
"post_id" : 112,
"post_date" : "October 3, 2016",
"title" : "hjhjhjhjkljkhasfreiwutb cltjutjuregjre nb0",
"show_comment_number" : "1",
"show_likes" : "1",
"post_img" : [
   {
    "guid" : "http:\/\/myUrl\/wp-  content\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1475494067.jpg"
   }
  ],
  "author_img" : "http:\/\/myURL\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2016\/10\/Screenshot_1-2.png",
  "post_time" : "11:27 am",
  "blog_text" : "sfdhjusolidasfjgfkdsjfdklshfj0"
 },
 {
  "author" : "russell99",
  "post_id" : 129,
  "post_date" : "October 24, 2016",
  "title" : "russels 1st post",
  "show_comment_number" : "0",
  "show_likes" : "0",
  "post_img" : [
    {
      "guid" : "http:\/\/myURL\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1477280037.jpg"
    }
   ],
   "author_img" :    "http:\/\/muURL\/Content\/Images\/Products\/NoImageAvailable   .jpg",
   "post_time" : "3:33 am",
  "blog_text" : "russel post"
 },
 {
  "author" : "russell99",
  "post_id" : 131,
  "post_date" : "October 24, 2016",
  "title" : "russels 2nd post",
  "show_comment_number" : "0",
  "show_likes" : "0",
  "post_img" : [
    {
      "guid" :    "http:\/\/myURL\/wpcontent\/uploads\/2016\/10\/IMG_1477282075.jpg"
    }
   ],
  "author_img" :    "http:\/\/muURL\/Content\/Images\/Products\/NoImageAvailable  .jpg",
  "post_time" : "4:07 am",
  "blog_text" : "russel post 2"
}
])
```

as I am new to Alamofire, it's been pretty confusing for me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response is type of `Array` not Dictionary so set for loop this way.

```
for items in json.arrayValue {

    let author: String? = anItem["author"].stringValue
    let title: String? = anItem["title"].stringValue
    self.tableAuthor.append(author!)
    self.tableTitle.append(title!)
}
```

**Note:** Instead of using multiple array you need to create array of custom type like `[Book]` for that first you need to create custom class `Book`.